# Do the dependencies in build.gradle generated automatically?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

Does gradle work like go mod ? First importing some dependencies in java file such as `import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper`, then calling `gradle build` and gradle would generate dependencies in build.gradle automatically, also download all the jars needed to gradle cache.

Or, all the denpendencies we need must add to `build.gradle` manully? Which version should append to the denpendency, search in the maven repo one by one?

Thank~

Comment: java `import` does not integrate with build; it's a compile time namespace feature (e.g. the class is always fully qualified in byte code). So it's the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle uses the dependencies declared in the build file to create the *compile* classpath. Similarly it will use test dependencies for the test compile classpath and the test runtime classpath.

So you have to declare the dependencies first, including figuring out which version you want to use in your project, and then you will be able to compile and run code that leverages these libraries.